# C - gets not working

Tags: c, gets

I'm having a problem with gets() working.
The thing is it should be working with just a warning from vars I am not using but the first gets just skips to the second.

```
int addClube(char *fileName)
{

        char qClube2[100], qClubeSimple[100], qEstadio[100], qCompleto[500],qAcronimo[100];
        int option=0;

        printf("\n  Indique o nome completo do clube:\n  (sem acentos)\n  ");
        gets(qClube2);

        printf("\n  Indique o nome simplificado do clube:\n  (sem acentos)\n  ");
        gets(qClubeSimple);

        printf("\n  Indique o acronimo do clube:\n  ");
        scanf("%s",qAcronimo);

        printf("\n  Indique o nome do estadio:\n  ");
        gets(qEstadio);

        return option;
}
```

The output I get when the function starts:

```
Indique o nome completo do clube:
(sem acentos)

Indique o nome simplificado do clube:
(sem acentos)
```

Once again thanks in advance for the help an if you more info just tell me.

Comment: You probably used `scanf("%d"` in a function prior to calling this

Comment: `gets` is inherently unsafe beyond repair, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: yes I did with when navigating from the menu
but then how do I solve that?

Comment: `scanf("%s",qAcronimo);` leaves the trailing `'\n'` in `stdin` for the next `gets()` to consume as an empty line.  Just use `fgets()`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try Using `fflush(stdin);` after all the gets() [Check This](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2012/12/Buffer--o-que-e-como-limpar-e-as-funcoes-fflush-e-fpurge.html);
Also, why are u using this option var for ?

Comment: ill try it;
that option var is to get back to the menu or just close the app.

Comment: Thanks it worked. ill vote up your answer when stackoverflow allows me.

Comment: No Problem, glad i could help :D

Comment: @Rafael Botas This answer recommended `fflush(stdin)`.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: `fflush()` is for output streams. Not input.

Comment: so do you have a solution for my problem? @PC Luddite

Comment: @RafaelBotas If you need to clear the input stream, there are several tricks and some implementations actually do support `fflush(stdin)`, but this is nonstandard and your code won't be portable.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to clear the input stream, `fflush(stdin)` will **not** do the job. It is my understanding that it works on Windows, but most other systems (UNIX, Linux) it is undefined behavior.

I wrote this on the fly, so it may or may not work, but essentially you need to discard all data you don't want. The following discards a line from the input buffer.

```
void clearinline(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while(c != '\n' && c != EOF)
}
```